# Find a Non-Duplicate Row in DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I'm currently working on scanning through a DataTable to look for a non-duplicate value in "ColumnA"

Please note that I am not looking for DISTINCT values because that will return one more than row of results.

Currently, when I google "c# Find non-duplicate row" I only receive results that deal with removing duplicates, which is not what I want to do.

For example:

If each row of 'ColumnA' contains:

1

1

1

2

1

I want to be able to pull the row that contains '2' as its value.

Is there a LINQ expression I can use to do this? I found some other SO questions and found answers that were close (except that, again, they returned DISTINCT rows).

I know that with SQL I can use the Count() expression to count the instances of a row, but I am doing this from a C# class.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In both LINQ and SQL you would use a group by construct for this, followed by restricting the results by count. The difference is that in SQL you would use `HAVING`, while in LINQ you would continue using `Where`.

Here is how it would look in LINQ:

```
var res = source
    .GroupBy(item => item.ColumnA)
    .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
    .Select(g => g.Single());
```

Comment: Hey this is great. Thank you. It returned the single row of results I needed. How do I access the individual objects in the ItemArray?

Comment: @terbubbs What do you mean by the `ItemArray`? Do you convert the results to array (i.e. add `.ToArray()` after `Select(g=>g.Single())`?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. In your example, when LINQ produces 'res', how can I extract the data from that? I had to reformat the LINQ a little by tagging 'AsEnumerable()' in front of .GroupBy() so I could get it working. When I added a breakpoint to 'var res', I took a look at the objects and found an array of the results I needed. I attempted to do 'res[0]' to pull the individual objects but that did not work.

Comment: @terbubbs LINQ queries return `IEnumerable<...>`, so if you would like to use an indexer you need to call either a `ToArray()` or a `ToList()` to `res`. You don't have to do it, though, if you'd rather iterate over the results with a `foreach` loop, as in `foreach (var item in res) {...}`

Comment: AHHH okay. That makes sense. End of the day mind fart. Thank you.